# If I have an indicator on my TradingView chart, but don't have its source code, can I still use its value in the Pine script of another indicator?

Tags: pine-script

I have a short-interest ratio indicator on my TradingView chart that is a community indicator that has been published without its source code.  Is there a way to access the indicator's value in another indicators Pine script?  The only way I found for merging indicators was to merge their Pine code, but since I do not have the code for this indicator, I wonder if there is another way to get to its value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but that indicator must be on your chart and the value you want to use must be displayed by a `plot()`. Then, you should use `input.source()` to fetch this source.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

in_src1 = input.source(close, "Source 1")
in_src2 = input.source(close, "Source 2")

plot(in_src1, color=color.white)
plot(in_src2, color=color.yellow)
```

Once you add your indicator to the chart, you need select the input you want to use from the drop-down menu.

[image]